# Why ClaimsPrincipal.Current is returned null even when the user is authenticated?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In an ASP.Net core 2.0 applicaiton (SPA with Angular), while User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is returning true, the ClaimsPrincipal.Current is always returned false!

I need it in another project where it is used not in a controller. What did I miss?

Comment: have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @NevilleNazerane this should be an answer.

Comment: well I have honestly never used SPA like angular to an extent to understand how this works. I don't follow the question or the link I posted entirely. So, someone can feel free to elaborate in the link and post an answer

Comment: have you tried with something like:                                                                        var id = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

                var us = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

Answer (score 11):

ASP.NET Core does not set `ClaimsPrincipal.Current`, if you need it, then you can set it in a middleware.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
...
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = context.User;
    await next(context);
});
```

The default claims principal selector is based on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` so it should work.